# How to inject sinon js to application in iFrame

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, iframe, sinon

I want to test ajax requests in my application.

The application run in an iFrame, and i want that the iframe's wrapper page will test the application with sinon (the wrapper will send the respond).

I tried to put in the `window's` object in the tested application the sinon's fake server (`sinon.fakeserver.create()`), but when send the respond to the ajax call, it didn't work.

Hope that the idea is clear and understandable.

Thanks for helping out,

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.

Once you call `sinon.fakeserver.create` the `window.XmlHttpRequest` will be replaced by sinon object.

And you can assign and overwrite the target window object, for example

`var server=sinon.fakeserver.create();
document.getElementByID("iframe").addEventListener("load", function(){ 
 document.getElementByID("iframe").contentWindow.XMLHttpRequest=window.XMLHttpRequest;
});`

Comment: Thanks, for answer, but it will not work (tried it). once I laod the  iFrame html src file, it will failed due to fake server creation.

Comment: It works for me nicely,, so I guess your Ajax call are used during page load not after.    And this solution depends on the onload event from the iframe

Comment: So in what order I need to do the things? put html in iFrame? addEventListener? create fakeserver?